# QTCreator and VisualStudio Code compilation with CMake

Tags: qt, visual-studio-code, cmake, qt5, qt-creator

I have a problem concerning the compilation of a program. I don't know why the same CMakeLists.txt is compiling in QTcreator and not in Visual Studio. I am using the exact same compiler which is MinGW for Windows. I have read the documentation, it compiles well **EXCEPT** if use a translation file ***untitled_fr_FR.ts***.

Please see the CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

#---------------------------------------------------------------------    
# I ADD THIS ONE TO COMPILE IN VSCODE AS ASKED IN THE DOCUMENTATION
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH} "C:\\Qt\\5.15.0\\mingw81_64")
#---------------------------------------------------------------------

project(untitled LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets LinguistTools REQUIRED)

set(TS_FILES untitled_fr_FR.ts)

  add_executable(untitled
    main.cpp
    mainwindow.cpp
    mainwindow.h
    mainwindow.ui
    ${TS_FILES}
  )

target_link_libraries(untitled PRIVATE Qt5::Widgets)

qt5_create_translation(QM_FILES ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} ${TS_FILES})
```

This code works well in QTCreator but gives me this error in VSCode:

```
[main] Building folder: untitled 
[build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --build c:/Users/remi/Desktop/ok/untitled/build --config Debug --target all -- -j 6
[build] [ 16%] Automatic MOC and UIC for target untitled
[build] [ 16%] Built target untitled_autogen
[build] mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** No rule to make target '../', needed by '../untitled_fr_FR.ts'.  Stop.
[build] mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:95: CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/all] Error 2
[build] mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:103: all] Error 2
[build] Build finished with exit code 2

***** No rule to make target '../', needed by '../untitled_fr_FR.ts'.  Stop.**
```

How can I solve this one? How can I figure out what QTCreator is changing in the CMake file/env to compile the .ts file?

Thanks a lot for your help, hope I'm clear and I don't bother you.

Comment: Perhaps, try removing the `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}` from the command: `qt5_create_translation(QM_FILES ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} ${TS_FILES})`. Including this `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}` argument will process sources in the `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR`, but it appears you already explicitly add `TS_FILES` sources from that directory, so having both arguments is redundant...

Comment: @squareskittles Thanks for your answer. It works better but still failed 
[build] [ 33%] Generating ../untitled_fr_FR.ts
[build] lupdate error: List file '' is not readable.
[build] mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\untitled.dir\build.make:81: ../untitled_fr_FR.ts] Error 1

Comment: Apologies, my previous comment may have been a bit misguided. The documentation for this [command](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtlinguist-cmake-qt5-create-translation.html) is a bit unclear. It seems it may require the `.ts` file listed to have a corresponding *source* file of the same name. So your `untitled_fr_FR.ts` file may require a corresponding `untitled_fr_FR.cpp` file. You might try renaming your `.ts` file to match that of one of your `.cpp` files.

Comment: Thanks

And... It works after renaming the untitled_fr_FR.ts to mainwindow.ts and change set(TS_FILES untitled_fr_FR.ts) to  set(TS_FILES mainwindow.ts).

But I don't understand why :
- I don't need to do this in QTCreator
- How it works if I have multiple windows ?

I'am new to stackoverflow, I don't know what to do now, do I need to answer to my own question ?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtlinguist-cmake-qt5-create-translation.html) I saw was not clear, and it's not clear why the change is not necessary for QTCreator. The docs suggest that the arguments can be ts files or sources, so for multiple files you may be able to do something like `qt5_create_translation(QM_FILES mainwindow.cpp mainwindow.ts otherwindow.cpp otherwindow.ts ... )`. I don't have a way to test it right now. But yes, it is helpful to answer your own question to document what worked, which will help future visitors to your quesiton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to include translation is not using this method. The CMakeLists.txt to compile the program is :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

#---------------------------------------------------------------------    
# I ADD THIS ONE TO COMPILE IN VSCODE AS ASKED IN THE DOCUMENTATION
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH} "C:\\Qt\\5.15.0\\mingw81_64")
#---------------------------------------------------------------------

project(untitled LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets REQUIRED)

  add_executable(untitled
    main.cpp
    mainwindow.cpp
    mainwindow.h
    mainwindow.ui
  )

target_link_libraries(untitled PRIVATE Qt5::Widgets)
```

If you want to compile it (out of the Qt environment you will need to use this one :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

#---------------------------------------------------------------------    
# I ADD THIS ONE TO COMPILE IN VSCODE AS ASKED IN THE DOCUMENTATION
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH} "C:\\Qt\\5.15.0\\mingw81_64")
#---------------------------------------------------------------------

project(untitled LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets LinguistTools REQUIRED)

set(TS_FILES mainwindow.ts)

  add_executable(untitled
    main.cpp
    mainwindow.cpp
    mainwindow.h
    mainwindow.ui
    ${TS_FILES}
  )

target_link_libraries(untitled PRIVATE Qt5::Widgets)

qt5_create_translation(QM_FILES ${TS_FILES})
```

And rename **untitled_fr_FR.ts** in **mainwindow.ts**